# How to compare IAT (Implicit Association Test) results of two different groups?

Tags: statistics, data

I already have the recommended algorithm [to analyse IAT data](http://faculty.washington.edu/agg/iat_materials.htm#). It allows to compare within-subject differences in response latency in the  congruent versus non-congruent condition.
However, in addition to analyzing the within-subject differences, I also need to know if the differences between two groups are statistically significant. How should I go about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [CrossValidate.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: IAT is a very specific measure to psychology research; so I assume it is reasonable to post here, even if it would also be relevant to crossvalidated.se

Answer (score 1):

I assume IAT gives you a score for each person.

I imagine you could just do an independent groups t-test to assess whether the means of the two groups significantly differ.